# Multiple frames with different viewmodels

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm developing WPF MVVM app and I have one main Window with two frames, and few pages. In the first frame, I navigate between pages, in the second frame I want to make it visible or hide it when I need it.

I have ViewModel for the Main Window and different ViewModels for the pages. To make visible or invisible the second frame I need another ViewModel that interacts with the frame.

Here's what I have:

```
<Window x:Class="MyApp.MyApp_Main"
        WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:atProp="clr-namespace:MyApp.AttachedProperties"
        xmlns:viewMod="clr-namespace:MyApp.ViewModel"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        x:Name="MainWin"
        WindowStyle="None"
        AllowsTransparency="True"
        MinHeight="{Binding WindowMinimumHeight}"
        MinWidth="{Binding WindowMinumumWidth}"
        Width="800"
        Height="500"
        WindowState="Maximized">
        ...

   <Grid>
        <Frame x:Name="MainPage"
               atProp:FrameHistoryClean.Value ="True"
               DataContext="{Binding Navigation.CurrentPage,
                                Source={x:Static viewMod:ViewModelLocator.Instance},
                                Converter={local:ApplicationPageValueConverter}}"
               Content="{Binding}"/>

        <Frame
            atProp:FrameHistoryClean.Value ="True"
            DataContext=""   <!--I don't know how to specify the ViewModel-->
            Content="{Binding}"
        />

    </Grid>

</Window>
```

Here is `ApplicationPageValueConverter`

```
public class ApplicationPageValueConverter : BaseValueConverter<ApplicationPageValueConverter>
    {
        public override object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
           
            switch ((ApplicationPage)value)
            {
                case ApplicationPage.StartUp:
                    return new StartUpPage(); 
                
                case ApplicationPage.Helper:
                    return new Page1();

                case ApplicationPage.Login:
                    return new LoginPage(); 

                case ApplicationPage.Test:
                    return new TestPage();
              
                default:
                    Debugger.Break();
                    return null;
            }
        }
     }
```

I don't know how to interact with the second frame to make it visible or invisible.

Any examples or suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: You have a controller the is parsing the response and depending on the type of response you are going to fill a different view model.  See : https://www.codemag.com/article/1201061/CODE-Framework-Writing-MVVM-MVC-WPF-Applications

Comment: I could make a new page and solve the problem. But any time when I need to navigate between the pages `ApplicationPageValueConverter` returns new Page, and I lost the data. I need to navigate between the pages without reinstantiate the ViewModel.I wanted to make it visible or invisible when I need it, in that way I'm not losing data

Comment: If you have two pages that use two request/browsers so when you navigate to 2nd page you still have the first page.

Comment: Your application is a HTTP Request and you are getting a HTTP Response.  The only difference when you use a browser is you get the response in a VIEW instead of as text.  The class ApplicationPageValueConverter is the parsed response from the request.  You are binding to "Navigation.CurrentPage".  If you want additional info from another page than do another request and put into a different class.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/overview/understanding-models-views-and-controllers-cs

Comment: But I'm developing a WPF MVVM app

Comment: You still have a client and server (a WPF platform).  See : https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/raj1979/simple-mvvm-pattern-in-wpf/#:~:text=MVVM%20is%20a%20way%20of,together%20with%20less%20technical%20difficulties.